# Recursion function with pushing parameters not work correct

Tags: assembly, x86

I have recursion function fun. When I push something, my eax not working ok. The value is not correct. I must push edx, because I need parameter for recursive function.

```
fun:
mov edx, [esp+4]
sub edx, 2
push edx
call fun
add esp, 4 ; not work ok
mov ecx,eax
sub edx,1
push edx
call fun
pop edx ;this too not work ok
add eax,ecx
ret
```

When I push something, eax not work ok. How can I fix that, if I want push edx and eax still work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `edx` and `ecx` to be preserved but they will of course be overwritten by the next recursion.

You might want to try something like this instead:

```
fun:
mov edx, [esp+4]
sub edx, 2
push edx
call fun
add esp, 4
mov edx, [esp+4] ; reload argument
sub edx,1
push eax ; save current result
push edx
call fun
add eax, [esp+4] ; add saved result
add esp, 8 ; remove argument and saved result
ret
```

Of course you will want to add code that stops the recursion ;)

Comment: `ecx` and `edx`. You expected both to be unchanged but you change them.